# how to assign value to combobox in datagridview

Tags: combobox

How to assign value to combobox in datagridview

```
Dim l As New ArrayList
        l.Add("Mouse")
        l.Add("Keyboard")
        l.Add("Laptop")


  CType(DataGridView1.Columns(0), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = l
```

Comment: Dim l As New ArrayList

        l.Add("Mouse")

        l.Add("Keyboard")

        l.Add("Laptop")


        'DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = l
        CType(DataGridView1.Columns(0), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = l

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of posting new infos into the comment section. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim l As New ArrayList 
l.Add("Mouse") 
l.Add("Keyboard") 
l.Add("Laptop")
```

Convert ArrayList to string array, or use string array instead of ArrayList

```
string[] items = (string[])l.ToArray(typeof(string));
```

Create a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and add the items as a range

```
Dim comboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
comboBoxColumn.Name = "Options"
comboBoxColumn.Items.AddRange(items)
```

Add column to the end of the datagridview

```
 DataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboBoxColumn)
```